# Regexp substitution and finite-state transducers

Tags: automata, regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions, transducers

Many programming languages support a "regular expression substitution" operation: if `r` is a regular expression and `s`, `t` are strings, `sub(s, r, t)` finds the first substring of `s` that matches the regexp `r` and replaces it with `t`.

Can this operation always be represented as a finite-state transduction?  In particular, are we guaranteed that for each `r`, `t`, there exists a finite-state transducer $T$ that implements the function `s` $\mapsto$ `sub(s, r, t)`?  Can it be done with a deterministic finite-state transducer?  If not, can it be done with a non-deterministic finite-state transducer?

---

Here's an example of a case that seems non-obvious to me.  Consider the regexp `00(00)*11`, e.g., the operation `sub(s, "00(00)*11", "2")`.  If we imagine trying to build a finite-state transducer for this operation, it seems like once it has seen `00` on the input, it has to keep reading `00`'s until it sees a `1` and not output anything until then (since it doesn't know whether this block will be of the form `0000...0011` or `0000..0010`).  If it sees `0000..0010`, then at that point has to emit all of the saved-up `00`'s.  But how does it keep track of how many to emit?  Finite-state machines can't count, so I can't see how to achieve this.

Comment: This operation *can* be implemented by _three_ finite transducers that are arranged in a configuration `c(reverse(b(reverse(a(x)))))`, where `reverse` reverses the input. The first transducer inserts start and end markers of possible matches, the second cleans those up and finds the *actual* start/end marker of the match, and the third one does the replacement.

Comment: Also, since reversing the input requires O(n) memory I wonder, is this model of `c(r(b(r(a(x)))))` as powerful as a pushdown automaton?

Comment: @orlp Actually two-way finite state transducers, which can walk up-and-down the input tape are a known model of computation.

Comment: @orlp By "pushdown automaton" you mean a transducer with an additional stack as storage? If I am not mistaken the domain (input strings of succesful computations) of a finite state transducers is regular, whereas a pda can accept non-regular languages. *groeten*